Bounding a complex polynomial on unit circle
For two non-negative integers $u$ and $v$, consider the following polynomial:
$$P(z):=(z^2-2z-1)^u\cdot (z+1)^v.$$
I would like to find the maximum of $|P(z)|$ on the unit circle $\{z\in\mathbb C:|z|=1\}$in the complex plane:
$$M:=\max_{|z|=1}|P(z)|.$$
So far, I was only able to find a bound on $M$: since $|z^2-2z-1|$ is bounded on $|z|=1$ by $2\sqrt 2$, and $|z+1|$ is bounded by $2$, we can deduce that $M\leq 2^{3u/2+v}$. However, once both $u$ and $v$ are non-zero, we will not have equality since both factors are not maximized for the same $z$-value.
Do there exist methods to find the maximum $M$ exactly? Or to find a tighter bound?

What happens if you construe $~z = x + iy,~$ set $~y = \pm \sqrt{1 - x^2}~$ (i.e. potentially two cases), and then construct (in effect) $~Q(x) = P(z),~$ and then compute $~Q'(x) ~?~$  Have you tried this approach?  If so, please edit your posted question to include such an attempt, regardless of whether the attempt succeeds.

For what it's worth, virtually every MathSE posted question that I have seen, that followed this article on MathSE protocol has been upvoted rather than downvoted.  I am not necessarily advocating this protocol.  Instead, I am merely stating a fact: if you scrupulously follow the linked article, skipping/omitting nothing, you virtually guarantee a positive response.

One possible approach is to realize that any point on the unit circle can be written as $z = e^{i\theta} = \cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$.
Then you can use this substitution turns it into a 1D calculus problem.

 The (squared) magnitude is $(6 - 2\cos(2\theta))^u(2+2cos(\theta))^v$ if I calculated things right. Taking the derivate with product + chain rules should not be hard.

